# PDF is generated but file not retrieved in a webView in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, webview

I am generating a PDF of a `UIView` and storing with a name in `myforms` the PFD is being generated and console prints PDF is Available but it shows nothing but a white screen in VC

here is what I am doing :

I have this code to generate a PDF

```
   @IBAction func createAct(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Creat PDF")
    self.createPdfFromView(mainView: mainView, saveToDocumentsWithFileName: "myforms")
}


func createPdfFromView(mainView: UIView, saveToDocumentsWithFileName fileName: String)
{
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, mainView.bounds, nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()

    guard let pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

    mainView.layer.render(in: pdfContext)
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

    if let documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first {
        let documentsFileName = documentDirectories + "/" + fileName
        debugPrint(documentsFileName)
        pdfData.write(toFile: documentsFileName, atomically: true)
    }
}
```

then I have this in console :

Creat PDF

`"/Users/jawaidahmed/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3F95BE09-0F25-427C-9ED9-4BDB16DC3600/data/Containers/Data/Application/1EC22FBC-79E7-4AC5-BB7D-13783CC34516/Documents/myforms"`

and I am using this `PDFViewController` to retrieve the file in a webview

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

       let check = "myforms"

    var pdfURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last! as URL

    print("check final = \(pdfURL)")

    pdfURL = pdfURL.appendingPathComponent(check) as URL



    if let pdfBundleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myforms", withExtension: nil, subdirectory: nil)  {




        do {

            let data = try Data(contentsOf: pdfBundleURL)



            //Lastly, write your file to the disk.

            try data.write(to: pdfURL, options: .atomicWrite)



        }

        catch {

            // catch errors here

        }

    }



    do{

        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String

        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        var filePath = url.appendingPathComponent(check).path

        let fileManager1 = FileManager.default

        if fileManager1.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {

            print("FILE AVAILABLE in VC")

            filePath = "file://\(filePath)"

            let fileUrlkk = Foundation.URL(string: filePath)

            let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrlkk!)

            self.webView.load(data, mimeType: filePath, textEncodingName:"utf-8", baseURL: pdfURL.deletingLastPathComponent())

        } else {

            print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE in VC")

        }

    }

    catch let error as NSError {

        print("An error took place: \(error)")

    }

}
```

And I am receiving this in console :
`FILE AVAILABLE in VC`

It means file is generated and available but it shows only empty VC white background only

Comment: What is `filePath` after executing: `var filePath = url.appendingPathComponent(check).path`?

Comment: when you are saving the document you are not writing the extension ".pdf".

Comment: @Alexkater so how should I do athat

Comment: @iOSDeveloper 
On this line
    self.createPdfFromView(mainView: mainView, saveToDocumentsWithFileName: "myforms.pdf")

Comment: @Alexkater its not working dear!!

Answer (score 0):

```
self.webView.load(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName:"utf-8", baseURL: pdfURL.deletingLastPathComponent())
```

replace textEncodingName:""

with

textEncodingName:"utf-8"

check it

Answer (score 0):

Try this for loading in Webview.I tried with your sample..It works

```
let FileName = "myforms"   
let Filemanager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()  
let docURL = Filemanager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as NSURL  
print(docURL)   
let pdfPATH = docURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(FileName)        
print(pdfPATH)           
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: pdfPATH)  
WBview.loadData(data!, MIMEType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: pdfPATH.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent!)
```